# How to merge/combine two values into single key in the same array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am not sure what is the appropriate terms to use for my title but just wondering to have below solution where need to merge/combine two values into one within a associative array.
For example I have this array:

```
Array
(
 [1] => Array
    (
        [agent_name_1] => Agent 1
        [agent_phone_1] => 0123456
        [agent_company_1] => My Company
        [agent_email_1] => agent@yahoo.com
        [agent_address_1] => United States
    )

 )
```

Here I would like to combine `company_1` with `address_1`. So the output should be like this:

```
Array
(
 [1] => Array
    (
        [agent_name_1] => Agent 1
        [agent_phone_1] => 0123456
        [agent_email_1] => agent@yahoo.com
        [agent_address_1] => My Company, United States
    )

 )
```

Please someone help me to find out the easiest way to solve this issue.

Comment: combine them into a single string? or into an array with two values stored at the original key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to loop through the array and modify the corresponding key of the original array.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $agent) {
  $array[$key]['agent_address_1'] = $agent['agent_company_1'] . ', ' . $agent['agent_address_1'];
  unset($array[$key]['agent_company_1']);
}
```

Read more about the [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) control structure and how it loops through arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_map()` in your code like this:

```
<?php

$MyArray[1] = array (
        'agent_name_1' => 'Agent 1',
        'agent_phone_1' => '0123456',
        'agent_company_1' => 'My Company', 
        'agent_email_1' => 'agent@yahoo.com', 
        'agent_address_1' => 'United States'
    );

$array = array_map(function($n) {$n['agent_address_1'] = $n['agent_company_1'] . ', ' . $n['agent_address_1']; unset($n['agent_company_1']); return $n;}, $MyArray);

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [agent_name_1] => Agent 1
            [agent_phone_1] => 0123456
            [agent_email_1] => agent@yahoo.com
            [agent_address_1] => My Company, United States
        )

)
```

Read more at:

> http://php.net/array_map