# Concatenate values in an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a csv file from which selected items are to be displayed. Eg:

```
Name, Surname, ID, Job, Salary, DOB
adam, Parker, 123, admin, 500, 19.02.1988
joe, Oswald, 897, sales manager, 750, 10.04.1967
```

I want an array that stores values as:

```
Name, Surname, ID, Job, Salary, DOB
adam Parker, Parker, 123, admin, 500, 19.02.1988
joe Oswald, Oswald, 897, sales manager, 750, 10.04.1967
```

I have referred this([How to merge/combine two values into single key in the same array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505098/how-to-merge-combine-two-values-into-single-key-in-the-same-array)), but doesn't work for more than one single row.

Comment: That's not associative arrays. You should also include what ever code you've tried. You have tried something, right?

Comment: No code, no problem explanation, no research. Please motive us to help you

Comment: Is there any rule about which strings should get concatenated and which should not?

Comment: I recommend you read  the theory http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php

Comment: ...and also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

A little Theory:
An array is a matrix / vector / array that stores values in 3 possible ways depending on its type.

- Numeric array
- Associative Array
- Multidimensional array

**Numeric array**
It is a type of array that has numerical indexes and is accessed with a whole number to each value of it.

example:

```
$numeric_array = array($value1, $value2, $value3,...);
```

a complete example:

```
$name = "Aner"; 
$numeric_array = array(1, 2, 3, "home", $name);

//get the length of array
$length = count($numeric_array);

//for cycle
for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++)
      {
      //get value of each element's array
      echo $numeric_array[$i];
      echo "<br>";
      }
```

other method for acces to values is by index example:

```
$numeric_array[0];//this get the first element
```

**Associative Array** this is an array whose values are assigned by keys:

```
$assoc_array = array(key1=>value1, key2=>value2, key3=>value3...);
```

example:

```
$equipe = array(goalie=>'Cech', defending=>'Terry', medium=>'Lampard', Forward=>'Torres');

foreach($equipe as $position=>$player)
    {
    echo "the " . $position . " is " . $player;
    echo "<br>";
    }
```

othe method for access is by the key:

```
 $equipe['goalie']
```

**Multidimensional array** A multidimensional array is an array containing one or more arrays.

PHP understands multidimensional arrays that are two, three, four, five, or more levels deep. However, arrays more than three levels deep are hard to manage for most people.

The dimension of an array indicates the number of indices you need to select an element.

- For a two-dimensional array you need two indices to select an element
- For a three-dimensional array you need three indices to select an
  element

**Two-dimensional Arrays** example:

```
echo "3-dimensional array:<br>";

$product=array(
            array(
               array("Epson Printer L110",100,4500),
               array("Canon Printer",100,5000),
               array("HP Laptop",500,40000)
            ),
            array(
                array("Micromax Canvas Lite",200,9000),
                array("Samsung Galaxy",300,15000),
                array("LAVA",100,4000)
            ),
            array(
                array("Sandisk 16 GB Pendrive",500,500),
                array("Card Reader",500,50),
                array("UPS",200,3000)
            )
);

// accessing elements from 3-dimensional product array.
echo "<table border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=5>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Product</th>";
echo "<th>Quantity</th>";
echo "<th>Price</th>";
echo "</tr>";

for($l=0;$l<3;$l++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    for($r=0;$r<3;$r++)
    {

        for($c=0;$c<3;$c++)
        {
            echo "<td>".$product[$l][$r][$c]."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";

    }

}
echo "</table>";
```

[image: outputArray]

I suggest you read [Arrays  Doc official](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: This only answers the OP's misunderstanding of what you call specific types of arrays (which the OP can read about in the manual). It doesn't  answer the actual question question in any way.

Comment: ...also, the example for "three-dimensional" arrays won't work as you expect. You overwrite `$dates` (which you use in the outer loop) in the inner `foreach()`.